# HTTP helper class in a thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am writing an app for android that connects to a server to get/post some xml data. I currently have a small class with static methods such as post(string URI, string body) and get() that wrap the httpclient calls to create a http post request and return the response. I am wondering if i should also have these method work in their own threads. Currently, i need to do a async task to call my Helper.post(..) method to connect to and get a request from a server. Is it better to just have the async stuff incorporated in the helper class to avoid having multiple repeated async tasks all across my app to just make post calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general principle it is best to wrap up repeated code so that you dont continually re-invent the wheel.  Therefore if it is possible for you to wrap up the threading easily then it would be a good idea to do so.

This is not always very easy. Methods which *get* something from the network define want done with that data once it's been received.  Usually you just return it. But if you're threading within the method then you have to *push it somewhere*.  This leads to a lot of additional callbacks and you dont (in my experience) save much.

Rather than defining a bunch of static methods which do the threading for you, I would recommend you keep threading out of the static methods and define a bunch of abstract AsyncTasks instead. Each defines it's own [doInBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) and leaves the [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) and [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) methods undefined.  That way you get the best of both worlds - you re-use as much as possible (the `doInBackground` code) but are able to customize where the data is sent once received.

**Example**

Your static code:

```
public class MyStaticClass {

    public static String getFoo( String name ) {
        // use the network to get a string;
        return "hello " + name; // Use your immagination.
    }

}
```

An `AsyncTask` defined as `public` so that it can be re-used easily.

```
public class GetFooTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground( String... name ) {
        return MyStaticClass.getFoo(name[0]);
    }

}
```

Now to use it.  Your static library or public async task could not have known what you need to do with the resulting string.  So you tell it what to do with the result here:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_view);

        // You've already defined how to get the data 
        // so using it requires only minimal code now.
        GetFooTask titleTask = new GetFooTask() {
            @Override
            public void onPostExecute( String heading ) {
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.heading)).setText(heading);
            }
        };
        titleTask.execute("John");
    }
}
```

In this example you can use the `GetFooTask` in as many activities as you like, just tell it where to put the data each time.

If you really think you will never want to do two network tasks on the same thread then you can combine the static code and the "abstract" `AsyncTask`.  But more often than not I find I want to fire several things to and from the network before I finally return a result.  If I did the threading in the network static code I would end up firing 10 threads for one request... therefore I keep threading out the static code.

Comment: I am not quite clear what you are suggesting. Would it be ok if you gave a sort code sample of what you mean by getting the best of both worlds?